# Turing Machine transition table

Tags: turing-machines

I am trying to design transition table for Turing Machine for adding binary number 3 dec or 11 bin to any another binary number.
First state = q0, Σ = {0,1}, empty symbol = Θ.
Is there any difference between L,1,q3 and 1,q3,L?
Should "L,1,q3" move head to the left, write 1 and go to state q3?
Should "1,q3,L" write 1 and go to state q3, move head to the left?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference if you write first on the tape and then move the head or if you move the head first and then write on the tape. What exactly are you asking or what is the problem you have?

Comment: Thank you! You dispelled my doubts.